# Concatenating variables into a string for a query url

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to program a dynamic url that changes as the day changes. I can get the query to run if I hardcode the date into the string but it will not run when "todaysDate" is used at the end of the url. I looked in the locals window and the variable url returns the correct string needed to download the csv file that the query calls for.
'''

```
Sub historicalDataQuery(ByVal ticker As String)
Dim todaysDate As String
Dim oneYearAgo As String
Dim url As String

todaysDate = Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD")
oneYearAgo = Format(Now - 365, "YYYY-MM-DD")
url = "https://www.nasdaq.com/api/v1/historical/" & ticker & "/stocks/" & oneYearAgo & "/" & todaysDate
'On Error Resume Next

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="2020-02-23", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(Web.Contents(url)),[Delimiter="","", Columns=6, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Date""," & _
    " type date}, {"" Close/Last"", Currency.Type}, {"" Volume"", Int64.Type}, {"" Open"", Currency.Type}, {"" High"", Currency.Type}, {"" Low"", Currency.Type}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Columns"" = Table.RemoveColumns(#""Changed Type"",{""Date"", "" Volume"", "" Open"", "" High"", "" Low""})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Columns"""
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=2020-02-23;Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [2020-02-23]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = ticker
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
end sub
```

for example, I know that this code works:

```
Source = Csv.Document(Web.Contents(""https://www.nasdaq.com/api/v1/historical/" & ticker & "/stocks/" oneYearAgo & "/2020-02-23"")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo in your query definition

I also refactored some of the code

**Code:**

```
Sub test()
    historicalDataQuery "msft"
End Sub

Sub historicalDataQuery(ByVal ticker As String)
    Dim todaysDate As String
    Dim oneYearAgo As String
    Dim url As String
    Dim queryName As String
    Dim queryString As String

    todaysDate = Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    oneYearAgo = Format(Now - 365, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    url = "https://www.nasdaq.com/api/v1/historical/" & ticker & "/stocks/" & oneYearAgo & "/" & todaysDate

    queryName = ticker & todaysDate

    If QueryExists(queryName, ThisWorkbook) Then
        MsgBox "Query already exists"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    queryString = "let" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
                  "    Source = Csv.Document(Web.Contents(""" & url & """),[Delimiter="","", Columns=6, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
                  "    PromoteHeaders = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
                  "    ChangeTypes = Table.TransformColumnTypes(PromoteHeaders,{{""Date"", type date}, {"" Close/Last"", Currency.Type}, {"" Volume"", Int64.Type}, {"" Open"", Currency.Type}, {"" High"", Currency.Type}, {"" Low"", Currency.Type}})," & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
                  "    RemoveColumns = Table.RemoveColumns(ChangeTypes,{""Date"", "" Volume"", "" Open"", "" High"", "" Low""})" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
                  "in" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
                  "    RemoveColumns"

    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=queryName, Formula:=queryString

    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & queryName & ";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & queryName & "]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = ticker
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub

Function QueryExists(q$, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    ' Credits: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/VBA-to-automate-Power-956a52d1
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    QueryExists = CBool(Len(wb.Queries(q).Name))
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: This worked right until it hit the ticker BRK.B and threw and error saying the query name contains invalid characters. But that's on me. I didn't specify in my question that this runs for many different stock tickers. This runs in a loop which deletes each query as it goes so the name can be the same for each essentailly.